# get rid of annoying default piano roll sound in FL studio

Tags: recording, fl-studio, studio, controller

I connected my roland gaia and am now using it as a midi controller. I also want to record the actual sounds from it. I got this to work except for the fact that FL studio's default piano roll sound plays every time I play a note or chord. (Even during/after recording). How do I get rid of this?